macOS development: failed to refresh AppShortcut parameters
I am trying to build an application that uses AppIntents. Specifically, I am trying to run the sample program here on macOS 18.1:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appintents/acceleratingappinteractionswithappintents
This is the warning I get when I run it within XCode (newlines added):
Failed to refresh AppShortcut parameters with error: 
Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 
"(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.private.xpc.launchd.app-server AND 
originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.assertiond.system-shell AND 
originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.launchprocess)"
UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=(
originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.private.xpc.launchd.app-server AND 
originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.assertiond.system-shell AND 
originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.launchprocess)}

Any help would be appreciated.
To run the app at all, I chose Sign to Run Locally. I have also confirmed that the warning has to to with Intents. E.g., if comment out the following line in AppIntentsSampleApp.swift, the warning goes away:
        TrailShortcuts.updateAppShortcutParameters()

I've also confirmed that none of the shortcuts the app tries to register work in Siri or appear in the Shortcuts app.
